# How do I parallel write JSON files to a mounted directory using Spark in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have an `RDD` of 50,000 JSON files that I need to write to a mounted directory in Spark (Databricks). The mounted path looks something like `/mnt/myblob/mydata` (using Azure). I tried the following, but it turns out that I can't use `dbutils` inside a Spark job.

```
def write_json(output_path, json_data):
     dbutils.fs.put(output_path, json_data)
```

What I currently must do is bring the data locally (to the driver) and then call the `write_json` method.

```
records = my_rdd.collect()
for r in records:
     write_json(r['path'], r['json'])
```

This approach works, but takes forever to finish. Is there a faster way?

Comment: What does your rdd look like? Does it have one fully formed json per records?

Comment: yes, one well-formed json per record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to perform this operation in parallel.

```
def write_json(output_path, json_data):
    with open(output_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(json_data)

my_rdd.map(lambda r: write_json(r['path'], r['json']))
```